# Using AWS worker to delete old DB entries?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-rds, elastic-beanstalk

I have an app on AWS using Elastic Beanstalk/RDS/EC2/etc.

The app has some database entries that need to be deleted after a certain time. I've tried to set up a cron task on the main server, but found that the web server cannot handle tasks like this, and a worker has to be created instead.

So, after writing up a quick worker based on [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html), it seems that I cannot have the worker connect the existing database.

Am I overthinking this? I just need a way to have traffic come in, interact with the website, and then delete entries over time as they become irrelevant.

Comment: Why can't the webserver handle this?

Comment: From what i've found, the webserver isn't able to run background tasks.


(edit: at least, that's from my understanding of this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html)

Comment: The Worker approach is designed to address the issue of deciding which host should run a job when you have a cluster of application hosts (and how to autoscale the environment if the job consumes resources).  An alternate, perhaps simpler, approach would be a scheduled lambda function that cleans up your data. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html